# How to join two tables and use it as jpa repository

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I don't speak very well in English, so I used translate.google)).

I have database in MySQL:

[image]

And my Entities:

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
public class Role {
   private Integer id;
   private String roleName;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
   public Integer getId() {
       return id;
   }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

   @Basic
   @Column(name = "role_name", nullable = false, length = 255)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   public String getRoleName() {
      return roleName;
   }

   public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
       this.roleName = roleName;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
       Role role = (Role) o;
       return Objects.equals(id, role.id) &&
            Objects.equals(roleName, role.roleName);
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {

       return Objects.hash(id, roleName);
   }
}
```

**User.java**

```
 @Entity
 public class User {

    private Integer id;
    private String login;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "login", nullable = false, length = 255)
    public String getLogin() {
       return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
       this.login = login;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getEmail() {
       return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
       this.email = email;
    }

   @Basic
   @Column(name = "password", nullable = true, length = 255)
   public String getPassword() {
       return password;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password) {
       this.password = password;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
       User user = (User) o;
       return Objects.equals(id, user.id) &&
            Objects.equals(login, user.login) &&
            Objects.equals(email, user.email) &&
            Objects.equals(password, user.password);
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {

      return Objects.hash(id, login, email, password);
   }

   public User() {
   }

   public User(String login, String email, String password) {
       this.login = login;
       this.email = email;
       this.password = password;
   }
}
```

**UserRole.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role", schema = "liverpool_site", catalog = "")
public class UserRole {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer userId;
    private Integer roleId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
       return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getUserId() {
       return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
       this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getRoleId() {
       return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(Integer roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserRole userRole = (UserRole) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, userRole.id) &&
                Objects.equals(userId, userRole.userId) &&
                Objects.equals(roleId, userRole.roleId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

          return Objects.hash(id, userId, roleId);
    }

    public UserRole() {
     }

     public UserRole(Integer userId, Integer roleId) {
         this.userId = userId;
         this.roleId = roleId;
    }
}
```

**Okey, that my question:**

Now how these tables join and that it can be used as a jpa repository, as that:

```
public class UserRoleJpa{
    private Integer idUser;
    private String login;
    private String email;
    private String roleName;

    //getter and setter methods
}


public interface UserRoleJpa extends JpaRepository<UserRoleJpa, String> {
      //for example
      List<UserRoleJpa> findAll();
}
```

**I will be very glad for any advice and ways how to implement this.**

**If possible using Spring Data JPA))**

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have your `UserRole` entity have references to `User` and `Role` rather than their IDs? (you can use the `@ManyToOne` annotation for this)

Comment: of cource I can added in UserRole:'@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)' and '@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)'

Answer (score 0):

I think it 's better to define two entries User and Role and then map them with a `ManyToMany` annotation  That would create the table user_role which will contain both the id of the user and the role

You only have to add this to your user entity

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="USERS_ROLES")
private Collection<Role>roles;
```

And no need for the userRole entity